# What's the Windows equivalent of a UNIX shell script?

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, batch-file

I want to have an executable file that will call some other programs. The way I would do this in Linux is with a simple bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running some-program"
/home/murat/some-program arg1 arg2
```

What's the best way to do this kind of thing under Windows?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Take a look at [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C6EF4735-C7DE-46A2-997A-EA58FDFCBA63&displaylang=en), which is the closest you will get to a true scripting language like you have in Unix. Other than that, for simple things such as simply runnning an application, take a look at Windows command script/MS-DOS batch files.

Comment: The primary issue with PowerShell (for me, at least) is that it is currently not installed by default on most versions of Windows (including XP and Vista).  

However, it will be included out-of-the-box on Windows Server 2008 and on Windows 7: http://tinyurl.com/5jhh2f

Comment: Yes, PowerShell is not installed by default on any versions of Windows except Win7, which will actually be PowerShell v2.

Answer (score 16):

You could go with either an old school batch file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) or you can go with a brand new shiny Windows PowerShell script (http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/hubs/msh.mspx).

I use batch for simple operations and PowerShell for complex scripts that also involve  data processing.

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of scripting options on windows:

- Batch files
- VBScript/CScript/JScript (very powerful when combined with WMI)
- PowerShell
- You could install Perl, Python, or other engine
- You can install unix tools, via Cygwin for example, to get make most of the common unix commands available in windows as well.
- Since we're all (mostly?) programmers here, there's nothing stopping you from making a .exe file to do what you want.

Comment: Just to be clear, using powershell requires an install right now as well.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a Windows batch file. Find more information in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).

Answer (score 7):

The Windows NT family of Operating Systems (NT 3.51, NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Vista) have a reasonably powerful Command Shell even if it is a bit esoteric. This shell does not have the power of the typical UNIX shells however it is ubiquitous on Windows machines and it is pretty amazing what can be achieved. A great book for this is [Windows NT Shell Scripting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578700477) by Timothy Hill. I always found [Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) a great resource for batch files.

PowerShell is Microsoft's latest offering in this field and takes scripting to a whole new level and gives you access to all of the power of the .NET framework as well as WMI, COM and any other interface into Windows. There is a pretty steep learning curve with this but it is definitely the way to go and I think it has the potential to become one of those foundational technology skills (like RegEx, XPath etc) in the Microsoft world. A good starting point is [Microsoft Windows PowerShell Technology Center](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) but there are a huge number of resources out there for this.

Comment: Rob vandr Woude's Scripting pages are now here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php

Answer (score 6):

I used to use batch files. And for simple examples like you gave above I still do, but more and more I have been using [python](http://www.python.org/) to do these sorts of things. It has the added benefit of working across platforms for those rare scripts that are actually meaningful on multiple platforms.

Python is just one of many scripting languages you could use for this sort of thing. Perl, ruby, or php may be more your speed. I find that a scripting language gives me a richer and easier to understand syntax if I want to do something a little more complicated than just start a program with a few default arguments.

Answer (score 6):

As long as we're suggesting *nix command-line tools, I'd recommend checking out Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com) as it emulates a *nix-like environment.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: Wow, this is woefully out of date now (though that's inevitable). Powershell is definitely becoming more and more the language of choice for automation in Windows. It has many of the advantages of any .net language (like C#) combined with much of the expediency that exists in any good shell language, without the serious downsides of batch files.

For what it's worth, the most popular options I've seen at a certain large, Redmond based software company (in rough order of popularity):

- Batch  files
- Perl
- Windows Scripting Host (Javascript)
- Tiny exes

Much less popular:

- Powershell

Note that Perl doesn't require an install, it only requires a few environment variable updates, so it's easy to just shove a full distro into your source control system along with other tools.

My personal preference would be to avoid batch files as much as possible, even with the most careful and rigorous of processes the benefit for the cost is just not worth it. You'll never end up with a satisfactory solution if you use batch. Perl and Javascript are tempting to use but there are troublesome fundamental deficiencies which leave a lot to be desired, without strong development guidelines these methods will more likely than not lead to low quality code.

Python and Powershell are good candidates but I'm not sufficiently adept with them and, more importantly, a lot of people aren't that familiar with them. Perhaps that's not a good enough excuse. Tiny exes can have many problems as well and require discipline and process in order to ensure that the source is always checked in, that the exes conform to certain UI norms (e.g. they have useful help if you run -? or /?), that they have an obvious owner, that the process for updating the exes is discoverable, etc.

Answer (score 4):

batch files work for me.  Just remove the first line in your example and it should work the same in win32 cmd line.

note - make a text file, name it with a .bat extension and use a backslash rather than a forward slash.

Comment: He'll need to fix the slashes

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the underpowered Windows command line, the not very Windows-friendly Cygwin or the quirky and slow Powershell, you might consider [Hamilton C shell](http://www.hamiltonlabs.com/cshell.htm).  I am the author, so of course I'm possibly biased, but I am a real person and I do care about trying to make my customers happy. Hamilton C shell is a complete recreation of the UNIX C shell and utilities but all of it's from scratch for Windows and, as such, it's designed to follow the Windows conventions for filenames and so on.  I just released a new version this summer for Vista that includes both 32-bit and 64-bit builds.  (The 64-bit version is about 2x to 3x as fast as the 32-bit version.)  There's a free demo, so you can try before you buy.

Answer (score 2):

While shell have `sh -C ${custom command}`.

Try on `cmd /C ${custom command}` where ***${custom command}*** stand for the command you want to get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the windows command line (DOS) is considered rather impoverished compared to *nix. You could install something like Cygwin or PowerShell if you want a powerful command shell, or you could cause yourself great pain and suffering to try using DOS for all your needs. :)

Comment: Every Windows command script I've written in recent years won't run on DOS. The only thing you're inheriting from DOS are parts of the syntax and commands.

Answer (score 0):

WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

has been my win32 weapon of choice as of late.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of CScript/JScript.  Very powerful once you learn the available system objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example batch file I made for someone a while back.

```
echo off
echo Backing up Images
%homedrive%\Backup\7z.exe a -tzip photos.zip %userprofile%\Photos\*.jpg %userprofile%\Photos\*.png %userprofile%\Photos\*.gif %userprofile%\Photos\*.bmp
echo Backing up Music
%userprofile%\Backup\7z.exe a -tzip music.zip %userprofile%\Music\*.mp3 %userprofile%\Music\*.wma %userprofile%\Music\*.ogg %userprofile%\Music\*.wav
echo All Done
```

Note that the script expects to have the 7z.exe program in a folder called Backup in the %homedrive% location. I used Envirnment Variables to make it easier for different users.